# How to process two Array Objects without using EVAL

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, object

I want to process two objects.

**obj1** array object having formulas.

**obj2** having values.
I want to process/calculate both objects to get result such that key present in obj1 becomes actual key in output and value get processed with formula. Did it with EVAL but don't want to use eval it.

Please suggest any other method to do the same.

```js
const obj1 = [{ _id: '5 f467650890a7444d8d9ea5b', keyname: 'fTime', 
  PTag: '(FaultHrs*360)+(FaultMins*60)+FaultSecs',    __v: 0 },
  { _id: '5 f467650890a7444d8d9ea5b', keyname: 'rTime',
  PTag: '(RunHrs*360)+(RunMins*60)+RunSecs', __v: 0 }
]
const obj2 = { FaultHrs: 2, FaultMins: 0, FaultSecs: 49, RunHrs: 1, RunMins: 0, RunSecs: 0,}

const res = obj1.reduce((res, k) => {
  // find out parameters in formula
  const matches = k.PTag.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);

  // substitute them with numbers
  const newTag = matches.reduce((tag, m) => tag.replace(m, obj2[m] || 0), k.PTag);

  // calculate result
  res[k.keyname] = eval(newTag);

  return res;
}, {});

console.log(res)
```

Comment: If the input is trustworthy - guaranteed to be a mathematical expression, free of unsafe code - then `eval` probably is the best choice. It's not absolutely evil, it's just that it's *usually* not the right option - but this is one circumstance where it is, IMO

Comment: @CertainPerformance shouldnt `new Function()` be used over `eval()`?

Comment: @Ifaruki I don't see a reason to prefer one over the other here, do you have an idea?

Comment: @CertainPerformance i have readed that `new Function()` is better and faster but they didnt explained it in detail. if you take a look a the speed comparison https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/2858/0/eval-vs-new-function there is actally an difference

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try new function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `New Function()` construct, instead `eval()`. Change your code line

```
 res[k.keyname] = eval(newTag);
```

Into

```
res[k.keyname] = (new Function(`return ${newTag};`))();
```

But under the hood it's same eval() actually. Or you could try to roll your own math expression parser, through abstract syntax trees, but there's plenty of them in internet already and besides there is no guarantee that your parser will be superior to integrated and time tested JS engine expression parser.

Comment: Thank you, new Function works as expected. I wanted to know - How to handle values like 6.7452824E7 and wanted to know am I using right approach to handle the Object arrays.

Comment: Escape your variables in expression with specific character, marking it to be different than `E` symbol used for scientific representation of numbers, like `PTag: '(_RunHrs*360)+(_RunMins*60)+_RunSecs'`. Then match against only those replaceable characters like `const matches = k.PTag.match(/_[a-zA-Z]+/g);`. In this way you will skip processing what's not a variable.

Comment: one more help I require, few of my parameters contains underscore and digits. So when I add them like this   const matches = k.PTag.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/g); My output comes wrong.

Comment: How you will escape variables in formulas is just your taste-, just escape it with symbol that never existed in your variables earlier. Maybe `@var@` or even with symbol train like `::var::`. And don't forget to change your regex matching your vars correctly !

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a module such as [math.js](https://mathjs.org/index.html), it includes an evaluate function which does not use *eval* under the hood (I believe an older version did).

There are still security risks, they are detailed in the math.js documentation [math.js security](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/security.html), but they should be lower than using eval directly.

```js
const obj1 = [{ _id: '5 f467650890a7444d8d9ea5b', keyname: 'fTime', 
  PTag: '(Fault_Hrs1*360)+(Fault_Mins1*60)+Fault_Secs1',    __v: 0 },
  { _id: '5 f467650890a7444d8d9ea5b', keyname: 'rTime',
  PTag: '(RunHrs*360)+(RunMins*60)+RunSecs', __v: 0 }
]
const obj2 = { Fault_Hrs1: 2, Fault_Mins1: 0, Fault_Secs1: 49, RunHrs: 1, RunMins: 0, RunSecs: 0,}
const res = obj1.reduce((res, k) => {
  // find out parameters in formula
  const matches = k.PTag.match(/([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/g);
  
  // substitute them with numbers
  const newTag = matches.reduce((tag, m) => tag.replace(m, obj2[m] || 0), k.PTag);
  // calculate result, using math.js evaluate function.
  res[k.keyname] = math.evaluate(newTag);

  return res;
}, {});

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/7.2.0/math.js" integrity="sha512-O3GZu6Lz0va4Lk7IuF3CjKx5Jfxi35Gcx3oAjH7m7KRP5xvqorrInDpg3OFVJ6dMPn03vHiwgkgPT/hWfguVfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, math evaluate works fine as expected. Just wanted to know is there any way to handle values like "6.7452824E7" which contain E.

Comment: I believe math.js should handle that format, I'll add an example to my answer..

Comment: one more help I require, few of my parameters in PTag contains underscore and digits. So when I add them like this   const matches = k.PTag.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/g); My output comes wrong.

Comment: Hey @GunjanAnshul, I've updated the answer. The problem is that if we use (/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/g as the regex expression, then we'll get numbers as matches. So I've added in the requirement that the PTag starts with an alphabetic character. This will then give the right answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved lot of time.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Math.js evaluate function works fine, but when values like **3.2477216E7** comes which contains alphabet "E", then it breaks. can u please let me know, how to handle that.

```js
const obj1 = [{ _id: '5 f467650890a7444d8d9ea5b', keyname: 'fTime', 
  PTag: '(FaultHrs*360)+(FaultMins*60)+FaultSecs',    __v: 0 },
  { _id: '5 f467650890a7444d8d9ea5b', keyname: 'rTime',
  PTag: '(RunHrs*360)+(RunMins*60)+RunSecs', __v: 0 }
]
const obj2 = { FaultHrs: 2, FaultMins: 0, FaultSecs: 3.2477216E7, RunHrs: 1, RunMins: 0, RunSecs: 3.2477063E7}

const res = obj1.reduce((res, k) => {
  // find out parameters in formula
  const matches = k.PTag.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);

  // substitute them with numbers
  const newTag = matches.reduce((tag, m) => tag.replace(m, obj2[m] || 0), k.PTag);

  // calculate result, using math.js evaluate function.
  res[k.keyname] = math.evaluate(newTag);

  return res;
}, {});

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/7.2.0/math.js" integrity="sha512-O3GZu6Lz0va4Lk7IuF3CjKx5Jfxi35Gcx3oAjH7m7KRP5xvqorrInDpg3OFVJ6dMPn03vHiwgkgPT/hWfguVfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```